# Opening a link in a different active window

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I have two browser windows open. One is a website assistant, the other is the actual website that assistant is related to.

If a user clicks a link from the assistant window, is it possible to trigger the loading of that page/link to appear on the second window instead of the assistant window?

I have no code for this, simply a question before I go any further.

A perfect example is www.ikea.co.uk. Click 'ask anna' in the header, and ask her 'how much is a bed'. The links it provides will open in window #1.

Comment: will this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903815/how-to-open-link-url-in-specific-browser-tab-window-page help you ?

Comment: Yes, using Javascript `window.open()` and identifying with a name.  Check this page out for a quick run-down:  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_name.asp.  Then you change your link to say `<a href="..." target="NAME">`

Answer (score 0):

How do you open the windows? With Javascript? Define a name to each frame/window and call for them on links. Something like that:

```
<iframe name="two"><iframe>

<a href="two.html" target="two">link</a>
```

Comment: The first frame is not named as it's just loaded up as normal when someone finds my site and goes onto it. The second 'assistant' window is loaded up with target="_blank".

Therefore I am unsure how I'd be targeting the main window when I have no initial control over the name its given (if any).

Comment: Jordan, so do you have a site (first window) that loads a popup (second window) and the popup has a link to open something in the first window? I'm thinking how you can do. Maybe you can create a label with CSS/JS instead another window.

Comment: Yep that's exactly it. User clicks 'Website Assistant' on the site, gets the popup window, and from there on any link they press such as "view delivery details" loads on window #1.

I absolutely need the popup window still. Something they can have open and move around while the main site (window #1) is still full screen behind.

Comment: A perfect example is www.ikea.co.uk. Click 'ask anna' in the header, and ask her 'how much is a bed'. The links it provides will open in window #1.

Comment: Jordan, this site uses a label with CSS/JS, not another window or frames.